# I need to overwrite the stdout for one line, and then revert the change

Tags: python, nltk, sys

This is what I have:

```
cfd1 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(biglisttagged)
sys.stdout = open(corpus_name+"-pos-word-freq.txt",'w')
cfd1.tabulate()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ #this is supposed to revert the change, but it doesn't.

print("helloword") #I need this to print to stdout
```

This is because tabulate() automatically writes to stdout, and I need it to write to the file.

However, my problem is this makes stdout not work for anything else in the program.

In the above example, helloworld would not get printed, what do I need to change?

Comment: I'd suggest you making a pull-request to NLTK which adds an optional parameter to make possible calls like `tabulate(file=sys.stdout)`. It would be the most clean solution.

Comment: Where are you running this from and what version of python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sys_stdout  = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open(...)
...
sys.stdout = sys_stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cfd1 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(biglisttagged)
stdout_save = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open(corpus_name+"-pos-word-freq.txt",'w')
cfd1.tabulate()
sys.stdout = stdout_save

print("helloword") #I need this to print to stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running this? I get this behaviour on IDLE, where the normal `stdout` has been replaced, and `__stdout__` set to `None`.

You could use `unittest.mock.patch` to handle the temporary redirect of stdout for you. Using the `with` statement means that stdout will be reset, even if there is an exception in your code block.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

cfd1 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(biglisttagged)

with open(corpus_name+"-pos-word-freq.txt", "w") as redirect, \
        patch("sys.stdout", new=redirect):
    cfd1.tabulate()

print("helloword")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by calling the script that redirect the stdout to a file and gets the relevant values as arguments and then continue the flow in the calling script without redirecting the stdout:

**test1.py**

```
    import sys
    cfd1=sys.argv[1]
    sys.stdout = open(corpus_name+"-pos-word-freq.txt",'w')
    cfd1.tabulate()
```

**test2.py**

```
cfd1 = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(biglisttagged)
execfile("test1.py " + cfd1)
print("helloword")
```